# Using jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an @Html.edifor to show date of birth and I want to use jquery datepicker to show calendar.
My scritp code is located in an external js file and proper reference to the file is on the view.
I am also using bundle in app config.

here is my script

```
$(function () {
    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Jquery?v=gywVLk6VvVVR_J6-oRPIvBpBvXSXEW6ZffeMhgu--bE1:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function.
```

here is my bundleConfig

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"));
        //css  
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssjqryUi").Include(
               "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));
```

Can someone help me spot what is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you load the jQuery UI Datepicker library?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded it

Comment: And you have a `<script>` tag that loads it?

Comment: I have it reference in my bundleconfig file.

Comment: jQueryUI depends upon jQuery.  Where do you add jQuery itself to the bundle?

Comment: You should have a `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` line somewhere in a CSHTML file somewhere...

Comment: sending it to you now

Comment: Yes, I have but when saying that, after I update packages in Visual Studio, I lost my layout, I dunno why? I have @Scripts.render in my _layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration and the Datapicker reference must be done before the JQuery Reference.

You must load jQuery or relative first.
Then Datapicker.
Then the call to initialize the datapicker.

Comment: I think to get this to work you have to place the script on the view where you want the datepicker to show, not on an external js file. This is how I got it to work.

Comment: @Schleid if that's the case, your problem is another one not specified in your question, because it's not relevant where are you calling the js code.

Comment: I was thinking about that too, would you give me an example please I would appreciate

Comment: @Schleid I believe is some personal election, but i dont use bundle, just reference the script as the usual kind. I did it for MVC 3 and change the method in 4, 5 and Core just because I dont see any good reason to use it. More then, if I can use it, I'll select a CDN source instead sharing the resource. But again, using the scripts in the order that to be need used, jquery first, dependencies after. My custom code after all.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Schleid you're welcome. If my answer help you please upvote it! Thanks in advance :)